# npm-gcm does not send notification to the device

Tags: android, node.js, google-cloud-messaging

guys, I want to send a notification to the android device using npm-gcm
and here is my code:

```
var sender = new gcm.Sender('myAPIkey');

var message = new gcm.Message();

message.addNotification('title', 'Backend!!!');
message.addNotification('body', 'Bitch');
var regTokens = ['deviceToken1'];
console.log(message)
regTokens.push('deviceToken2')

sender.send(message, { registrationTokens: regTokens }, function (err, response) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
        else console.log(response);
});
```

and in the console I get:

```
{ multicast_id: 7664202372197545000,
  success: 2,
  failure: 0,
  canonical_ids: 0,
  results:
  [ { message_id: '0:1481660978053751%cc7dad02f9fd7ecd' },
    { message_id: '0:1481660978045814%cc7dad02f9fd7ecd' } ]
 }
```

but the devices did not receive any notification. What is the problem?
Why is this happening? Can you give me an advice?!

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34251092/5832311),there might be an issue with "notification" object on node-gcm code. Try to use `message.addData` and check if it works. Make sure that you followed this [tutorial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gcm) and this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16418334/5832311) that gives sample code on how to send simple message to your device.

```
var sender = new gcm.Sender(googleApiKey);
var message = new gcm.Message();
message.addData('key1','testdarinodegcm');
message.delay_while_idle = 1;
var registrationIds = [];
registrationIds.push('APA91bHCzBP6wEfExCZlSXgf0wuOC6QEWJ-7MVFl3hgaW3Jv8FslsofGJ-      qgdliyS8zjwy_W7zPaKsEZx6kbeuWdoAAexawKl1Qd6GEGV_v844n1LMRaTsWeiwI9iaLGKKq_R3scY_wuRG8uG2SZ5X9q0J67Ko3gcw');
sender.send(message, registrationIds, 4, function (err, result) {
console.log(result);
});
```

Hope this helps!